React "soft" re-render after a Form submission
I'm trying to re-render the view without refreshing the page after a form submission (due to the loss of states)
This is my handleSubmit function:
 function handleSubmit(e:any) {
    // Prevent the browser from reloading the page
    e.preventDefault();

    const location = e.target[0]?.value;
    console.log('Location Changed To: '+ location);
    setWeatherLocation(location);
    
    // Function Calls
    fetchForecastData();
    fetchWeatherData();
    fetchTimeData();

  }


return (
......
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    something
</form>
)

All the new data gets pulled perfectly but the view doesn't get updated with the new data via the function calls.
• I can confirm the data is being pulled correctly, but isn't displayed. Instead the old data is still present on screen. (Although in memory it had been changed)
If I update the code in VSCode and click CTRL+S (Save) it "soft" refreshes the page and the new information is displayed correctly.
How can I force the same "soft refresh" after the Form submission?
Or any hard refresh without the loss of state data?
